# Ruby on Rails: Not loading views as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

I am new to Rails (and this site) and working through a Lynda.com tutorial. I have run into many issues because the tutorial was made about 3 years ago an it seems that the programming language has changed along the way. Luckily I have figured out how to get around most of the issues, but there is one particular one that keeps me from moving forward.

Versions:

Ruby 2.0.0p195

Mysql 14.14 dis 5.6.12

Gem 2.0.3

I am trying to connect to different **.html.erb** pages in my demo folder, but they are not being recognized by the **def** in my script.

visual examples here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56018487/rubyexample.png

It is my understanding that the "def hello" and "def other_hello" should automatically look for hello.html.erb and other_hello.html.erb files in my demo folder under views in my application. However, when I run the server and type those locations in the address bar, Firefox does not find them using localhost:3000/demo/hello or localhost:3000/demo/other_hello. I am sure it is something really easy, but I have not found the answer after 2 days of web searches.

As part of my trouble shooting efforts, I have tried each individual variation under the "def index" section that has been commented out. I can get to each page from the "def index" section when not commenting out **get "demo/index"**, but not from the "def hello" or "def other_hello" sections.

**Update:**
It is my goal to get a dynamic answer to my issue. In Rails 2, there is an elegant, single line of code that handles all incoming information.

I hope this makes sense.
Please let me know if you have suggestions.

A shout out to zeantsoi and Muntasim for your help in this matter. I would give each of you a point, but the site does not allow me to do that.

Comment: First off, let me thank you for your replies. I greatly appreciate your help in this matter. I have looked over the initial responses and I can get the "hard wired" answers to work, but I am looking for a  dynamic code solution. The original code line " match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))' " was an attempt to allow one line of code the flexibility to cover any request coming to the page rather than having to create a new line of code for each page. I am not sure if that is still possible with Rails 3x, but that is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: I see. As an FYI, it is __not__ possible to route a wildcard match to different actions based on the value. The controller and action must be defined – all that can be dynamic are the arguments passed in, which are passed as params to the action.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, the tutorial I am following thats gets the dynamic line of code to work in Rails 2, is no longer available in Rails 3. Correct?

Comment: What tutorial are you following? The line of code, as such, is a general pattern for explaining how RESTful routes are mapped.

Comment: you can use `match ':controller(/:action(/:id))'` to allow dynamic segments in routes

for more information visit http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I am following the Ruby On Rails tutorial on Lynda.com. I've been a member of Lynda.com for a while now and this is the first tutorial I have used that has had this many issues. Just older software.

Comment: Okay, finally got a grasp of what you're asking. Updated solution correspondingly. Please consider editing your question to expand the scope of your question to include dynamic routing.

Comment: So I finally figured it out with the help of zeantsoi, Micheal Durrant, and Muntasim.

The dynamic answer I was looking for...

SimpleCms::Application.routes.draw do

   root 'demo#index'
   get ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
end

I tried using Muntasim's "match" code suggestion, but it just wouldn't work for some reason. However, as all of the suggestions involving "get" commands worked, I took a chance and replaced "match" with "get" and it magically worked.

Comment: You can't use render or redirect more than once in action

Answer (score 2):

it seems you didnt define you routes yet. you can make sure by runnng `rake routes` and see if your routes are there. Otherwise define routes using:

```
# config/routes.rb
match 'demo/hello', 'demo#hello'
match 'demo/other_hello', 'demo#other_hello'
```

or simply:

```
get 'demo/hello'
get 'demo/other_hello'
```

Comment: When I run the Rake Routes, the rake is aborted and I get a "missing :controller" message along with a list attempts.

Comment: See comment under original question.

Comment: use `  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))'` to allow dynamic segments

for more information visit http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

You are missing routes to your `DemoController` actions. Add them like this:

```
# config/routes.rb
match 'demo/hello', 'demo#hello'
match 'demo/other_hello', 'demo#other_hello'
```

With these routes in place, you can access the `hello` and `other_hello` actions by visiting the paths `demo/hello` and `demo/other_hello`, respectively.

One other thing you may consider is adding a name to your route, which vastly facilitates routing from controllers and views:

```
# config/routes.rb
match 'demo/hello', 'demo#hello', :as => demo_hello
```

Then, in your view (or controller), you can use the following:

```
demo_hello_path #=> /demo/hello
demo_hello_url #=> hostname/demo/hello
```

EDIT:

If you're looking to dynamically route to your controller and action, you can use the following match pattern:

```
# config/routes.rb
match ':controller/:action'
```

Be warned that depending on what order this route is executed, it may override (or be overridden by) other hardcoded routes.

As an FYI, the [section on dynamic segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments) from the official Rails routing guide is helpful in figuring out how things are mapped.

Comment: Yes routes connect your pages to your controller actions.  In rails 2.x a default rule allowed the assumptions your are talking about but that was removed a couple of years ago with rails 3.

Comment: Ah. So that is what I am missing. That functionality was removed and I am working with an antiquated version of a Rails tutorial. Good to know so that I do not drive myself crazy.

Comment: Did this answer effective address your question? If so, would you kindly consider accepting it as correct? It's considered both helpful and polite to do so: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I am checking the answer as we speak.

Comment: See comment under original question.